# Deleting dup DB2 data from CTE

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following DB2 code which lists some duplicate incorrect rows, that I need to delete.  Can anyone help turn this into a delete statement?

```
with AN as (select AN 
            from SCHEMA1.ACCR 
            where TIME = '2013-06-01')  
select * 
from AN a 
inner join SCHEMA1.ACCR b 
        on a.AN = b.AN 
where TIME = '2012-06-01'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you attempting to delete all rows that have duplicates of some key?  Or only one of the entries?  If you're attempting to delete only one of the entries of a completely duplicated row, dumping the table and loading `DISTINCT` entries may be an option (especially if the count of duplicates is high).  Otherwise, you'll need to add some sort of unique key to be able to determine 'which' entry to delete...  Please give a sample data set for us to help you better.

Comment: What version of DB2 are you running, and on what operating system?

Comment: DB2 v9.7.0.6
AIX I believe

Comment: Clockwork-Muse, I inserted 27 records yesterday using the date '2012-06-01' instead of '2013-06-01'.  I later inserted the correct rows, but need to delete these.

A co-worked wrote this CTE query to find the rows that need deleted.  I just need the query to delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up using:

```
DELETE
from SCHEMA1.ACCR b 
WHERE AN IN  (select AN from SCHEMA1.ACCR where TIME='2013-06-01') 
AND TIME'2012-06-01'
```

Thanks for the questions/suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

```
with AN 
as (select AN 
from SCHEMA1.ACCR 
where TIME='2013-06-01')  
delete b
from AN a 
inner join SCHEMA1.ACCR b 
on a.AN=b.AN 
where TIME='2012-06-01'
```

Comment: On what version of DB2 have you tested this solution? This does not look like valid syntax.